# Variable variables created within a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, variable-variables

I'd like to change this:

```
if ($week_day == "1")
{
$day1_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "2")
{
$day2_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "3")
{
$day3_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "4")
{
$day4_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "5")
{
$day5_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "6")
{
$day6_hours = $value;
}
if ($week_day == "7")
{
$day7_hours = $value;
}
}
```

Into something more readable, like a for loop, or whatever other suggestions you all may have.

I tried to do:

```
for ($c=1; $c<8, $c++)
{
if ($week_day == $c)
{
$day".$c."_hours = $value;
}
}
```

But I know that is nowhere near correct, and I have no idea how to insert another variable within a variable.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set an array key? `$day[$week_day] = $value`

Comment: Perhaps! Elaborate on that?

Comment: @RobDubya  .... That's pretty much it, actually :D

Comment: Check manual for more info http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. Please try your own code. Posting invalid syntax doesn't show an attempt at solving the problem...

Comment: Could you post the full code for this situation as an answer? Declaring the array and so on?

Comment: @RobDubya - it's literally one extra line, the where you declare the array. You'll end up with an array where the key is the $week_day value, and the value is whatever's in $value.

Comment: I also need the _hours portion of the variable for stuff further along in the code, will it keep that, so would $day[$week_day]_hours = $value work?

Comment: You can replace it with `$day[$week_day]` - that's what you're setting value to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax.

```
${'day'.$c.'_hours'} = $value;
```

Comment: No joy, loads a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$hours[$week_day] = $value
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$week_day = 3;
$value = "hi";

${"day" . $week_day . "_hours"} = $value;  

echo $day3_hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation.

```
$week = 7;
$day = array();

for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++){
   $day[$i]['hours'] = $value;
}
```

You can declare the numbers of weeks you want and to pull the data you can do something like this:

```
echo $day[1]['hours']
```